# Refresh host a records for a server when changed in domain controller

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, hosts

In Active Directory DNS Manager, when I change the IP Address of a Host A record, how can I ensure the changes are replicated to all or specific computers in the domain.

[image: AD Host A]

When I change the IP Address to another server, when I ping the FQDN on the computer, it resolves the old IP Address; even after a restart.

I have tried a `ipconfig /flushdns` after rebooting the computer but to no avail.

### Further Information

My computer is registered on a different domain on the network, however the OS is installed on a Hyper V machine running locally on my computer.

To work around this I can edit the `etc/hosts` file and apply the lookup in there which works around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the cache of the DNS server itself too.
See [here](https://activedirectorypro.com/clear-windows-dns-cache/) in the section "Clear DNS Cache on Windows DNS Server".